# Why does the number of processes affect the output format when using multiprocessing.Pool(N)

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I have [taken this code](https://gist.github.com/ngcrawford/2237170) and modified it slightly to suit Python3.8.

The issue I am having is that the output initially has some sort of windings characters in it, I suspespect this is a newline charactor that is being incorrectly converted?. See output snippets below.
I couldn't work this out so before spending too much time on it, I tested the program with different numbers of processes. For some reason the output changes when I increase this.

```
import multiprocessing
from textwrap import dedent
from itertools import zip_longest

def process_chunk(d):
    #test function, change this later
    return d 

def grouper(n, iterable, padvalue=None):
    return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)

outfile= open("C:/Users/#####/Desktop/test.txt","w+")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #open input file
    test_data = open('D:/test.txt')

    # Create pool (p)
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    for chunk in grouper(1000, test_data):
        results = p.map(process_chunk, chunk)
        for r in results:
            outfile.write(f'{r}')
```

The below samples are of the end of file so I suspect the 'None' and 敮 output is just part of a chunk Expected output:

```
5.2615 19.522 -0.968 3 134 120 124
5.9195 19.695 -0.828 49 197 192 170
6.0985 19.192 -0.984 0 150 137 130
5.2255 19.915 -0.939 3 92 92 81
6.3825 19.286 -1.166 5 100 99 92
5.8965 19.705 -0.411 67 211 209 205
```

With **multiprocessing.Pool(4)** (same output for N=2 to N=10)

```
5.9195 19.695 -0.828 49 197 192 170਍ഀ
6.0985 19.192 -0.984 0 150 137 130਍ഀ
5.2255 19.915 -0.939 3 92 92 81਍ഀ
6.3825 19.286 -1.166 5 100 99 92਍ഀ
5.8965 19.705 -0.411 67 211 209 205਍ഀ
潎
```

With **multiprocessing.Pool(12)** (same output for N=11 to N=24)

```
5 . 2 6 1 5 1 9 . 5 2 2 - 0 . 9 6 8 3 1 3 4 1 2 0 1 2 4

5 . 9 1 9 5 1 9 . 6 9 5 - 0 . 8 2 8 4 9 1 9 7 1 9 2 1 7 0

6 . 0 9 8 5 1 9 . 1 9 2 - 0 . 9 8 4 0 1 5 0 1 3 7 1 3 0

5 . 2 2 5 5 1 9 . 9 1 5 - 0 . 9 3 9 3 9 2 9 2 8 1

6 . 3 8 2 5 1 9 . 2 8 6 - 1 . 1 6 6 5 1 0 0 9 9 9 2

5 . 8 9 6 5 1 9 . 7 0 5 - 0 . 4 1 1 6 7 2 1 1 2 0 9 2 0 5

None
```